# Why can't I use structs with data on my pallet error?

Tags: pallet, error

I have this code that will not compile :

```rs
#[pallet::error]
pub enum Error<T> {
 SomeErr{ account : T::AccountId }
}
```

This will not compile with the error :

> `AccountId` associated type not found.

Alright, can I help the situation by restricting `T` to `T: Config` ? No, that will not compile either. So does that imply we can't use `T` and it's ATs on Errors?

Or is it a general limitation on the Error type to not be able to nest other types? Which also brings me to the question, when using `map_err` a common pattern to wrap perhaps a failure from some other module and emit it as our custom pallet error, do we lose the ability to nest error types?

Effectively making the `e` in `map_err(|e| ... )` useless?

Answer (score 1):

I think the current limitation lies in the size.

If I remember correctly, the previous discussion suggested making the encoded error 2 bytes in size and adding support for nested types.

You can nest specific errors, but not the generic one.

If you introduce generics here, what will be the impact on size...?

For more details, please refer to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/8081.

Comment: Can you list an example showcasing a nesting of concrete errors. I reckon even that's useful than having nothing at all.

Comment: https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/171023c12ea7b26ae135a0397bc7c610b53bbbb9/pallet/message-transact/src/lib.rs#L107